# conversion of factor to numeric not working through as.numeric(as.character(data$variable))

Tags: type-conversion

I'm trying to create a data frame and apply some functions on it. However, the columns created by be are factors and I'm unable to convert them to numeric through as.numeric(as.character(data$variable)). I need my data to be in numeric form before applying the mean(variable) or sum(variable).

For example, I did this:

c("5","4","6")->height

data.frame(height)->data

as.numeric(as.character(height))

now, mean(height) is giving me an error: argument is not numeric or logical, returning NA

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
height <- as.numeric(height)
mean(height)
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
height <- as.numeric(height)
```

gives you NA NA NA NA NA NA NA you could try this trick:

```
sapply(height, as.numeric)
```